# Rollapply on large sparse matrices

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, rolling-computation

Is there a way to do a rollapply/rollsum to compute row sums on a **sparse** matrix over windows of fixed length? I'm working with `dgTMatrix` for convenience, but my problem is not specific to this class. For example, consider generating a `8 x 10` sparse matrix.

```
library(Matrix)
i <- c(1,3:8); j <- c(2,9,6:10); x <- 7 * (1:7)
A <- sparseMatrix(i, j, x = x, giveCsparse = FALSE)    

> A
8 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"

[1,] . 7 . . .  .  .  .  .  .
[2,] . . . . .  .  .  .  .  .
[3,] . . . . .  .  .  . 14  .
[4,] . . . . . 21  .  .  .  .
[5,] . . . . .  . 28  .  .  .
[6,] . . . . .  .  . 35  .  .
[7,] . . . . .  .  .  . 42  .
[8,] . . . . .  .  .  .  . 49
```

Without first coercing to a matrix, (e.g. as.matrix()), one naive approach is using `sapply` to compute row sums over every `window=2` columns, resulting in a `8 x 5` **dense** matrix .

```
window = 2
starts = seq(1,dim(A)[2],by=window)
A_rollsum <- sapply(starts, function(x) Matrix::rowSums(A[, x:(x+window-1)]))

> A_rollsum
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    7    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0   14
[4,]    0    0   21    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0   28    0
[6,]    0    0    0   35    0
[7,]    0    0    0    0   42
[8,]    0    0    0    0   49
```

This is not efficient for large sparse matrices.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck - Is there a way without coercing it to a standard `matrix`?

Comment: The matrices are not identical to `A_rollsum`. I've edited the question to reflect what `A` and `A_rollsum` should look like.

Comment: Your `A_rollsum` code doesn't work since by.column was not used. I have moved my comments to an answer and show that two ways of computing the result are the same.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that the last two `A_rollsum` should produce the correct matrix. The correct output is the one with the `sapply`, but I'd like to use something like `rollapply`. I will delete the last two to avoid confusion.

Comment: OK. I have revised it with a dense and sparse answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** `rollapply` works column by column and apparently you want row by row so transpose it, use rollapply as shown and transpose back:

```
t(rollapply(t(as.matrix(A)), 2, by = 2, sum))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    7    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0   14
[4,]    0    0   21    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0   28    0
[6,]    0    0    0   35    0
[7,]    0    0    0    0   42
[8,]    0    0    0    0   49
```

**2)** The above uses dense matrices but if you really need sparse matrices note that rollapply is a linear operator here so we can compute its matrix and then use sparse matrix multiplication.

```
d <- rollapply(diag(10), 2, by = 2, sum)
A %*% t(d)
```

### Old

The question was changed. this is the answer to the original question.

Try `r1`.  We show that it equals `r2`.

```
r1 <- rollapply(rowSums(A), 3, c)
r2 <- rollapply(as.matrix(A), 3, rowSums, by.column = FALSE)
identical(r1, r2)
## [1] TRUE
```

`r1` and therefore also `r2` equal:

```
> r1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    0   14
[2,]    0   14   21
[3,]   14   21   28
[4,]   21   28   35
[5,]   28   35   42
[6,]   35   42   49
```